# Tag a dominent Color name to an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using SKLEARN.CLUSTER and KMEANS to identify most dominant color in image using clustering algorithm (KMEANS).

Below code is used for cluster and histogram, In "clt" there is no way to tag or display the "BLUE" or most dominant color name into an image.

```
cluster = KMeans(n_clusters = 7)
cluster.fit(image)
h = utils.centroid_histogram(cluster)
print(cluster.cluster_centers_, h)
bar = utils.plot_colors(h, cluster.cluster_centers_)
```

The result is attached with this question,

Now my Question is: I want to tag a color name (BLUE) to the specific image. Because the BLUE is dominant color.

How I tag this "blue" word into my image.[image]
LIKE the below image, [image]

Comment: you want to overlay the word "BLUE" on your image and save it to a file?

Comment: When is `BLUE` the answer? You *need* to define some logic!